# How would you word this IF statement?

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I want to have an IF statement that:

```
if('number'.value = 0) {
    document.write("ERROR");
}
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: What is number a variable? Is it an object not much we can tell from this other than you are trying to check a string with a property which you also can't do and on top of that you need to use == for numbers and === for strings

Answer (score 2):

If number is a variable it is

```
 if(number == 0)
```

If number is a string and you are comparing it as a string then it will be false.

```
if("number" === "0")
```

If number number is an object containing a number with property value then

```
if(number.value == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition must be ==, not =. = its for assign value to var

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
if (number === 0) {
    document.write("ERROR");   
}
```

If you want to reference a variable, don't wrap it in quotation marks.  The way you have it, you are trying to access the `value` property of `string`, which doesn't exist (will return undefined).

Secondly, a single equal sign `=` assigns a value, not compares it.  If you want to compare equality, try `===` which will return true if the values on either side are of the same type and value.

Good luck learning :)

--edit--

Note that if your variable `number` is actually a string, use the `==` equality rather than `===`.  The `==` comparison doesn't check for types.